# How can I write a batch file that launch a http request everyday?

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file that sends the same http request everyday at a specific time.

I have tried this :

```
start http://mysite.org
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for Windows. It can send any request to given address.

```
wget http://mysite.org
```